# Why is my initial ramdisk so big?

Tags: kernel, compiling, initrd

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10, which came with kernel version `3.0.0-14`. I downloaded and built a kernel from the `3.1.0` branch. After installing the new kernel, I see that my `/boot/initrd.img-3.1.0` file is HUGE. It's 114MB, while my `/boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-14-generic` is about 13MB. I want to get rid of the bloat, which is clearly unnecessary.

When building the new kernel, I copied my `/boot/config-3.0.0-14-generic` to `.config` in my build directory, as to keep the configuration of my original kernel. I ran `make oldconfig`, selected the defaults for all the new options, and then built the kernel.

Looking at the file sizes within each of the initrd cpio archives, I see that all of my .ko modules are larger in size in the 3.1.0 ramdisk, than the 3.0.0-14. I assumed there was an unnecessary debug flag checked in my config file, but I don't see anything different that was not already enabled in the 3.0.0-14 config file.

My `/boot/config-3.0.0-14-generic` is here:
http://pastebin.com/UjH7nEqd

And my `/boot/config-3.0.1` is here:
http://pastebin.com/HyT0M2k1

Can anyone explain where all the unnecessary bloat is coming from?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When building the kernel and module using `make oldconfig`, `make` and `make install`, the resulting modules will have debug information available in the files.

Use the [`INSTALL_MOD_STRIP`](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kbuild/kbuild.txt#144) option for removing debugging symbols:

```
make INSTALL_MOD_STRIP=1 modules_install
```

Similarly, for building the deb packages:

```
make INSTALL_MOD_STRIP=1 deb-pkg
```

Comment: Running `make INSTALL_MOD_STRIP=1 install` got me what I wanted. Thanks!